# Fullcalendar swipe left-right function that also works well with dayClick

Tags: android, fullcalendar

How to implement touch device fullcalendar swipe functionality, that allows for me to change the month back and forth but also works well with dayClick or any other Click event on the diary ?

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I am definitely not against that. My concern is different.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 do tell, as it is still unclear ...

Comment: It was if my comment was not deleted.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Ah, figured it, his now deleted concern is that he was not given the chance to answer and get that valuable upvotes. The only reason I got down-voted is because "you posted your question and within a sec answered yourself" How rude of stack to provide the "Answer your own question" functionality ...

Comment: @Rohit5k2 you are in this site for the wrong reasons. Go code some clicker and make all the reputation you want for yourself. Some people are here to share knowledge and not cry for half hour.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 by the way, answers are open, you can still post yours, if it's better it will get more upvotes.

Comment: If a option is there then it doesn't mean can be used like this. And this will remain my opinion. I am not a php guy so I wasn't gonna answer this anyway. But just because I am allowed to carry a gun and guns are made for shooting, I can start to shoot everything. Can I?

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Do tell how is the "Answer your own question" option supposed to be used, when it's there before the question is posted. Apparently the site developers here have determined that posting question and answer is perfectly acceptable (I also linked you to a post of theirs), so if I shouldn't post a question I had, with the answer I came up, then how should I use the "Answer your own question" checkbox ? Also this has nothing to do with PHP, first part is pure native android java, second part is JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried many different solutions, Android classes, fullcalendar fixes, js libraries (hammer came close) nothing did the trick perfectly for me, apart from the bellow.

Assuming you have your fullcalendar in your WebView up and runing without problems:

In your Activity, you need to set a touch listener for your webView:

```
myWebView.setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                x1 = event.getX();
                                break;
                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                x2 = event.getX();
                                float deltaX = x2 - x1;
                                //check if the user's funger has moved significantly. Tiny bit of movement is very usual and common during touch, so >0 and <0 won't work.
                                if (deltaX < -210) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(deltaX), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //Swipes RtoL move to the next month
                                    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');");
                                } else if (deltaX > 210) {
                                    //Swipes LtoR move to the previous month
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(deltaX), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');");
                                } else if (deltaX > -210 && deltaX < 210) { //Adjust those numbers for your needs
                                    //itsa touch
                                    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript: goToDateClicked();");


                                }
                                break;
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

What this code does is check for a finger movement across the webView. If the finger movement is significant enough it is classified as a swipe and a javascript command is send to the calendar to flip the month.

If the finger movement wasn't significant enough, it most likely was a touch and a different command is send to the JS, one that gets the clicked day's date, go to that date, and change the view to a day view.

In your HTML then you will have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Declare a global date variable to set the callendar date to, when a day is clicked
var globalDate;

function goToDateClicked()
{
    //Change the view to a desired view and clicked date
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', globalDate );
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    //OPTIONS
         dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
         //On day click only set the date clicked. If it's a swipe then you don't have to worry about going back and forth into views and some weird logic to prevent swipe to date changes.
         //If it's a click then the Android code behind takes care of the date/view change, all it needs is the bellow date.
            globalDate = date.format();
        }
    });

    //DIARY RELATED BUTTONS CLICKS
    $(".fc-today-button").click(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
    });

});
</script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```